# camel spring xml are not loaded into fuse 7.x

Tags: jbossfuse, fuseesb

I had deployed camel spring xml bundle in fuse karaf 7.x series, As a result xml file was not loaded from bundle and camel contexts are not started. but it works in 6.x series.

I've tried bluprint xml bundle it works as expected but sping xml not.

could you please let me know should I install any feature in fuse karaf 7.x.

Answer (score 0):

Spring-DM (a.k.a. Spring-OSGi) is not supported in Fuse 7. It was deprecated back in Fuse 6.2 already:

- https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_fuse/7.0/html/release_notes/deprecatedandremoved#deprecatedandremoved-removed
- https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_fuse/6.2/html/release_notes/deprecated

You should use Blueprint applications instead of Spring-DM.